# Проект ASP.NET Core не запускается с IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, asp, iis-express

Создаю пустой проект, и запускаю с IIS Express, должен был открыться браузер. Но вместо этого получаю ошибку - "Отсутствуют компоненты для настройки и управления IIS Express". Обновил Visual Studio 2019, установил последнюю версию .NET (5) и .NET Core (3.1), но не помогло.[image: Отсутствуют компоненты для настройки и управления IIS Express]

Answer (score 0):

Поменял язык среды разработки Visual Studio 2019, с русского на английский, и теперь всё работает отлично, браузер открывается.